# Loading latitude/longitude from MySQL database and showing point on Google Maps using PHP,html and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, google-maps

I googled a lot but all the solutions i found didn't work for me (even google maps tutorial). I have a MySQL database where I store latitude and longitude values in Float type columns. I wrote php script which connects to the database and selects those values. The idea is that php script passes an array of longitude and latitude values to JavaScript and then Javascript iterate on that array making new markers on Google Maps. Here is my actual code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
 <style>
       #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 700px;        
        background-color: grey;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php 
  
$query ="SELECT latitude,longitude FROM markers"; 
 
 

$result_array=Array();

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port)
 or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error()); 

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
         $latitude=$row['latitude'];
   $longitude=$row['longitude'];
       $result_array[]=array('latitude'=>$latitude,'longitude'=>$longitude);
}
        
  $json=json_encode($result_array);
$con->close();

?>
<h3>MyMap</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            center: {lat: 41.5400 , lng: 12.2500},
            zoom: 6
        });
  var array="<?php echo $json_array;?>";
  
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   var myLatLng=new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
   var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map,
    position: myLatLng,
   });
  //}
  
    }
 </script>
 <script async defer
        src=MY GOOGLE API MAP>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me or suggest other ways to do the same thing?

Comment: What problem are you having?  What does the output of the database look like ($result_array)? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue you are having (with a better description of the problem than "it doesn't work")

Comment: The main problem is that JavaScript doesn't read the array made by php script. The array looks like [{"latitude":"40.808","longitude":"14.3026"},{"latitude":"40.8356","longitude":"14.3752"},{"latitude":"40.8432","longitude":"14.351"},{"latitude":"40.8117","longitude":"14.3551"},{"latitude":"0","longitude":"0"},{"latitude":"0","longitude":"0"},{"latitude":"40.5698","longitude":"14.5214"}] after json_encode. When, in javascript, i print the array in the console i get "<?php echo json_encode($result_array);?>" but not the content.

Comment: Where do `lat` and `lon` in the posted code come from?  How are you including the API (`<script async defer src=MY GOOGLE API MAP></script>` is obviously incorrect)

Comment: Lat and lon must come from array that javascript can'read. Of course i deleted google api, but in my source code google map loads well, the problem are markers that i can't set because i can't see the array php script makes

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. We don't need your PHP, the HTML & JavaScript that is served to the browser would help to identify the problem.

Comment: I already posted HTML & JavaScript... I'm just using embedded php... When i write var array="<?php echo $json_array;?>"; it's supposed to give array the value of $json_array that's in php script, isn't it?

Comment: What do you see in the HTML that is served to the browser?

Comment: I just see a google map without markers. Now i discovered that my embedded php isn't running, i changed the query in a insert one but nothing is inserted into the database. I renamed the file in index.php but it still doesn't work... can u tell me why my embedded php isn't executed when i load the web page?

Comment: Ok I wrote php block outside html and it works now, ty anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting newlines between `<?php` and the actual content, like so:

```
var array=JSON.parse("<?php
          echo $json_array;
          ?>");
```

The PHP substitution should put the double quotes on the same line.

Comment: I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token and if I use
 var array=JSON.parse("<?php echo $json_array;?>"); console says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: @Dan Does it just need to be in a try-catch loop or does it silently fail if you do?

Comment: What do you mean? I think the Unexpected token "<" is the first word of <?php echo $json_array;?> because when i print on console log the var array it prints "<?php echo $json_array;?>". Var array is supposed to store a json array, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 700px;        
        background-color: grey;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php 
        
$query ="SELECT latitude,longitude FROM markers"; 
    
    

$result_array=Array();

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port)
    or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());   

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
         $latitude=$row['latitude'];
         $longitude=$row['longitude'];
       $result_array[]=array('latitude'=>$latitude,'longitude'=>$longitude);
}
        
        $json=json_encode($result_array);
$con->close();

?>
<h3>MyMap</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            center: {lat: 41.5400 , lng: 12.2500},
            zoom: 6
        });
        var array="<?php echo $json;?>";//here changed
        
        for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            var myLatLng=new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
            var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                map:map,
                position: myLatLng,
            });
        //}
        
    }
    </script>
    <script async defer
        src=MY GOOGLE API MAP>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)